# About importing manager attribute to AD from a CSV

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to import manager attribute to active directory for set of users using the following CSV file template

```
GivenName   Surname DisplayName Department  Title      mail      MobilePhone    Manager SamAccountName
John        Smith   John Smith  IT          IT Manager john@example.com 1234   Mark Ebert JohnS
```

I used the below script and but it throws out an error.What i'm thinking it is due to manager attribute required to be in distinguished name format and **but i cannot change the csv manager  column name as it comes from a different program.****The manager name in the CSV file shows in first name and last name format**. What i need is to import the data on it to AD like the way it is.Any alternative methods available for this scenario.Here is the example script i used.

```
# Import AD Module           
Import-Module ActiveDirectory           strong text
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\MergedTo_AD.csv                     
foreach ($user in $users) 
{Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.samaccountname)'" | Set-ADUser -GivenName $($User.GivenName) -Surname $($User.Surname) -DisplayName $($User.DisplayName) -title $($User.title) -EmailAddress $($User.EmailAddress) -MobilePhone $($User.MobilePhone) $User -manager $ID }
```

Comment: You're using `-manager $ID` yet `$ID` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: in addidtion to Santiago's comment, you also have a random `$User` not assigned to anything, but alone after the `-MobilePhone` parameter. Seeing as the *Manager* field expects a SAMAccountName, objectSID, DistinguishedName, or GUID. . . you can query against the `$User.Manager` column/row first, using an ldapFilter: `$FirstName,$LastName = (-split $User.Manager).Trim()
$ID = (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(GivenName=*$FirstName*)(SurName=*$LastName*))").SamAccountName`. Which we first split the name into a first, and last name and then queried the 2 variables assigning it to `$ID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CSV looks like this:

```
GivenName,Surname,DisplayName,Department,Title,mail,MobilePhone,Manager,SamAccountName
John,Smith,John Smith,IT,IT Manager,john@example.com,1234,Mark Ebert,JohnS
Joe,Bloggs,Joe Bloggs,Marketing,Administrative Assistant,joe@example.com,87954,,JoeB
```

Then you can see that in the second example the `Manager` property is empty.
To best deal with columns that could be empty, use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) for properties that are present in the CSV, while omitting empty fields:

Something like this:

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\MergedTo_AD.csv
foreach ($user in $users) {
    # first try and find the user object in AD
    $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.SamAccountName)'" -Properties Manager -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($adUser) {
        # we have a valid user. create a splatting Hashtable to use with Set-ADUser
        # Leave out the Manager for now, as we first need to make sure we can actually find a DN for this property.
        $userProps = @{
            # take out any properties you do not want to (re) set
            GivenName    = $user.GivenName
            Surname      = $user.Surname
            DisplayName  = $user.DisplayName
            Title        = $user.Title
            EmailAddress = $user.mail
            MobilePhone  = $user.MobilePhone
        }
    
        # try and get the manager object from the $user.Manager column which may or may not have been set
        if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($user.Manager)) {
            # try and find an AD user with the given DisplayName. You could also try with the `Name` property
            $manager = Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($user.Manager)'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if ($manager) {
                # add the 'Manager' entry to the Hashtable for properties to set
                $userProps['Manager'] = $manager.DistinguishedName
            }
            else {
                Write-Warning "Could not find '$($user.Manager)' in AD.."
            }
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "Manager column for user '$($user.SamAccountName)' is empty.."
        }
        # here we set the properties to the user according to the CSV file
        Write-Host "Updating user properties for '$($user.SamAccountName)'"
        $adUser | Set-ADUser @userProps
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "User '$($user.SamAccountName)' could not be found.."
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Theo, Thank you so much.This script worked.There was a slight change i made as there was a missing bracket.You saved my day man ! Thank you so much !# try and get the manager object from the $user.Manager column which may or may not have been set
        if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($user.Manager)) {

Comment: @denprash Thanks. I don't know what happened there, but you're right, there was a bracket missing. Fixed that now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a scripting expert at all.I amended the script as below as per your suggestion.

```
# Import AD Module           
Import-Module ActiveDirectory           
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\MergedTo_AD.csv  
{Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.samaccountname)'" $FirstName,$LastName = (-split $User.Manager).Trim() $ID = (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(GivenName=*$FirstName*)(SurName=*$LastName*))").SamAccountName (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(GivenName=*$FirstName*)(SurName=*$LastName*))").SamAccountName| Set-ADUser -GivenName $($User.GivenName) -Surname $($User.Surname) -DisplayName $($User.DisplayName) -title $($User.title) -EmailAddress $($User.EmailAddress) -OfficePhone $($User.OfficePhone) -MobilePhone $($User.MobilePhone) -manager $($User.manager) }
```

I'm getting below error

```
Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized
At C:\Temp\PowershellScript-Users Import.ps1:5 char:128
+ ... im() $ID = (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(GivenName=*$FirstName*)(SurNam ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Comment: Separate the commands using a new line, or a semi colon `;`, and place the code I mentioned at the beginning of the loop, not in between.

Comment: Hi Abraham, I highly appreciate if you can put the entire code script here.I'm totally lost

Answer (score 0):

I've reviewed the code and the reason it fails is because you cannot add the manager using the variable '$ID' is that it has no reference, nor does it resolve to the managers active directory user account. Your choices are either add the managers Distinguished Name to your csv file or stick it in your code to resolve the managers Distinguished Name.

```
#Import CSV File to set variable for the user’s logon name of whom manager’s field needs to be filled + delimiter
$users = Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path  "C:\temp\MergedTo_AD.csv"

foreach ($user in $users) {
    #The Managers AD Sam Account Name
    $ManagersaMACCount = "saMACcount"
    
    #The Managers AD Distinguished Name
    $ManagerID = (Get-ADUser -identity $ManagersaMACCount).DistinguishedName
    
    #Example of Setting User's Manager Attribute -Example below
    #Get-aduser -identity $user | Set-ADUser -Manager $ManagerID
    
    #Using your code to filter AD Sam Accounts Based on column samaccountname in the csv file
    Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.samaccountname)'" `
    #Pipe Set Users GivenName Based on column GivenName
    | Set-ADUser -GivenName $($User.GivenName) `
    #Set Users Surname Based on column Surname
    -Surname $($User.Surname) `
    #Set Users Display Name Based on column DisplayName
    -DisplayName $($User.DisplayName) `
    #Set Users Title Based on column Title
    -title $($User.title) `
    #Set Users Email Address Based on column EmailAddress
    -EmailAddress $($User.EmailAddress) `
    #Set Users Mobile Phone Based on column MobilePhone
    -MobilePhone $($User.MobilePhone) `
    #Set Users Manager Based on the Distinguished Name Attribute In Active Directory
    -manager $ManagerID
}
```

Comment: Got this error when trying the given script.     +     |Set-ADUser -GivenName $($User.GivenName) `
+     ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement

Comment: Its a simple error, just change the location of the pipe... `  Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.samaccountname)'"  | `
    #Pipe Set Users GivenName Based on column GivenName
   Set-ADUser -GivenName $($User.GivenName) ``